# Why do planes accelerate when they touch down on a aircraft carrier

Tags: landing, aircraft-carrier, groundspeed

I was watching a plane documentary, and when the part about aircraft carriers came on, I noticed that as soon as the plane hits the aircraft carrier runways, the plane speeds up. ***Why*** is this happening?

The question has *not* been answered in [What is the procedure for landing on an aircraft carrier](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/475/what-is-the-procedure-for-landing-on-an-aircraft-carrier). This question explains the procedure to throttle up to full military power just after touchdown, however does not address the ***reason*** for doing so.

Comment: have you read ALL the answers? this one addresses the why: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/6297/1467

Comment: @Federico: _That_ answer does _not_. It does not even mention it! [_This_](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/480/524) one does, though.

Comment: how can you say that it does not? `Additionally the higher thrust setting minimizes any spool up time because you are already near max thrust.` what is this?

Comment: anyway, more than one answers mentions the why, hence this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Federico: That means higher thrust on final the answer generally talks about, _not_ the full thrust over threshold. Applying military (full dry; full otherwise means wet) thrust is no longer about minimizing spool time, it is about _starting the spool up already_.

Comment: @JanHudec the sentence before: `Upon landing this thrust becomes excess thrust enabling the aircraft to more quickly accelerate and get safely airborne in the event of a bolter.`