# What is the typical sink rate during a well-executed carrier landing at the moment the main wheels touch the deck?

Tags: aircraft-performance, military, aviation-history, pilot-technique, aircraft-carrier

What is the typical sink rate during a well-executed carrier landing at the moment the main wheels touch the deck?  And how has this changed over the decades?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the procedure for landing on an aircraft carrier?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/475/what-is-the-procedure-for-landing-on-an-aircraft-carrier)

Comment: from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9752/3394): "At the 90, altitude should be 450ft AGL, and VSI should increase to 500fpm"

Answer (score 15):

A lot. About **3-4 m/s (600-800 fpm)**. This is the speed at which 'normal' landing gear [begin to break](https://www.atsb.gov.au/publications/investigation_reports/2015/aair/ao-2015-032.aspx).

For carrier landings, there is no flare, so the touchdown speed equals to the sink rate on the final approach. The procedure in the [linked question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/475/what-is-the-procedure-for-landing-on-an-aircraft-carrier) mentions 700 fpm.

We can arrive at a similar figure if we consider the standard carrier glideslope [3.5°](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a258873.pdf) (pdf) and the typical approach airspeed of ~120-130 kn. If we allow 20-30 kn for carrier speed and headwind, then for 100 kn (51.4 m/s) closing speed we get 51.4 m/s * sin 3.5° = 3.14 m/s ≈ 620 fpm.

Comment: Yep, good answer.  600 was about what we would target.

Answer (score 3):

it’s dependent upon the aircraft in question and the approach speed that they need to use, but assuming a fighter aircraft like an F-18 with an approach speed somewhere in the neighborhood of 130 knots, a typical 3.5° glideslope to impact yields a descent rate on somewhere between 600-700fpm.   The faster the ship is moving and the greater the surface winds it’s steaming into, the lower the vertical speed will be on glide path to touchdown.

Comment: A carrier glideslope is 3.5 degrees.  And 6 months later, this answer doesn't really add anything...